# Cant get any Posted JSON data?

Tags: php, json

UserStore will .sync when the datastore are updated,

```
var UserStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        model: 'VehicleModel',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'get-vehicle.php',
            baseParams: {  //here you can define params you want to be sent on each request from this store
                        //groupid: 'value1',
                        },
            api: {
                    //create: 'update-vehicle.php',
                    //read: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=read',
                    update: 'update-vehicle.php',
                    //destroy: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=destroy'
                },
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json'

             }
        }
    });
```

when pressed the Save button, will call the UserStore to update the data with `update-
vehicle.php`

```
var BtnSave = Ext.getCmp('BtnSave')
BtnSave.on('click', function(){
onButtonClick();    
})

function onButtonClick(){
           var grid = Ext.getCmp('mygridpanel')
           var row = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
           var txtVehicleID = Ext.getCmp('txtVehicleID').getValue();
           var txtPlat_No = Ext.getCmp('txtPlat_No').getValue();
           console.log(txtVehicleID);

            var record = UserStore.findRecord('_id', txtVehicleID);
            record.set('_id', txtVehicleID);
            record.set('Plat_No',txtPlat_No);

            UserStore.sync();
            console.log("clicked");
}

}); // on ready
```

this is my FireBug Post Json Data i have seen

```
POST http://localhost/BusTicket/vehicle/update-vehicle.php?_dc=1386528763735
ParamsHeadersPostResponseHTML
JSON

Source
{"_id":"2","Plat_No":"AKC12342","id":null}
```

But, i can't get any data from my php page, this is my update-vehicle.php page, but get anything. Why?

```
<?php
echo $_POST['json'];
?>
```

### UPDATE

this is my firebug response header

```
Response Headers
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Mon, 09 Dec 2013 04:08:44 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/5.1
x-powered-by    ASP.NET, PHP/5.3.15
Request Headers
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length  42
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  PHPSESSID=78peh3ahri6s0nfraldjden5k0
Host    localhost
Referer http://localhost/BusTicket/vehicle/vehicle.html
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

when i `echo $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` html will print
`{"_id":"2","Plat_No":"AKC12341","id":null}`

but i m trying to use `$data = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA); echo $data;` $data is blank again...why?

Comment: print all post data print_r($_POST). where you pass json string in `json` variable?

Comment: The POSTed data doesn't look okay, something is buggy around your extjs post settings. Check another working js poster with firebug.

Comment: please help me to fix the code, i have been checked whole day for this JSON method, please

Comment: but my Firebug are shown JSON post record already, how come my print_r($_POST) is blank?

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that the json data is send directly through request body, not any `$_POST` param. You can access it using [http_get_request_body()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-body.php) function like this:

```
$data = json_decode(http_get_request_body());
```

Comment: i m trying to echo the json data i have received, but get nothing with this code `$data = json_decode(http_get_request_body());
echo $data;`

Comment: And what does the http_get_request_body() outputs?

Comment: how come like this, firebug are shown my Post JSON having the data already, why still is blank...sadnesss

Comment: `echo http_get_request_body();` is get nothing also

Comment: but i m trying to use `echo $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
$data = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA); 
echo $data;` $data is blank ...why?

Comment: Provide more details. For example `set_error_raporting` to `E_ALL` and see if there is any error shown also `var_dump($data)` and see what it contains. If it contains `false` then your JSON is malformed. With the information you provided it should work: [see it here](https://eval.in/77541).

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved with this following code :-

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$obj = json_decode($data);
print $obj->{'Plat_No'}; 
?>
```

because posting are raw data so need to use `file_get_contents("php://input");` or `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` only can get the post data.